# validate email with password in php

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I'm involved in a product development, where the user register his company. once he becomes user of our product, we need to send announcements,newsletters etc. to their users on behalf his company.

for this purpose we get his company email and password, i need to validate this email is valid and he's given correct password for the email id or not. I'am thinking about two methods to validate this email and password,

- Send a test mail with smtp authetication
- Try to open the inbox.

I feel the first one is better than the later. because if the user given wrong passwords, there are chances it will be considered as an attack.

Any one can tell me is there any better way to validate the given email with its password.

Answers appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You "get" his password?  That is, you are collecting the user's password for his own email?  Surely that can't be what you're doing.  It would be a gross violation of my company's security policy, not to mention idiotic, for me to hand out my email password to an unknown third party...  The mere existence of a requirement like that would be more than sufficient for me not to have anything at all to do with you, ever.

Comment: @ghoti: Because my service is sending mails to their users on behalf of his company.If i didn't have the password and  the receiving servers requires sender's email password to smtp auth, then this mail will be blocked right?

Comment: In his defense, what he's trying to do is send email on behalf of a 3rd party.  And although the specifics of what he's trying to do are grossly improper, there is certainly precedent for it in receiving mail (many CMS systems).  It seems what he's trying to do is recreate something like MailChimp.  My hat goes off to those guys, who know the specs inside and out. Sekar, either do all of the initial mail RFC reading, and compare that to actual usage in the wild (likely a year+ effort by several people assuming little background in the subject), or utilize a white-label service like Amazon SES.

Comment: Wrong, on so many levels.  Read up on [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/), learn how the envelope-from is handled (differently from the header-from), and ***DO NOT*** create services that force your customers to violate security best practices.  That will cause you to lose customers.  For an example of a company responsibly sending email on behalf of others, check out [Postmark](https://postmarkapp.com/).  You might even want to consider using their services instead of creating broken ones of your own.

Comment: @ghoti - Pretty much what I was trying to say, although you said it much better.  : )

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike - not necessarily better, just more emphatically.  :)

Comment: @JohnGreen-PageSpike: This is another approach. when the user registers his company we will a some configuration page, he'll place these pages in his site. so if he can add his email and password with that configuration, i can mail from his site itself. will it work?

Comment: @sekar - Managing that is a full time business in and of itself.  It is one of those things where if you have to ask, you have no business doing it yourself.  

Check out Postmark or Amazon SES.

Answer (score 1):

Just connect with [imap_open()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) and test if the connection was successful.

```
$resource = sprintf("{%s:%s/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/notls/norsh}INBOX","imap.host",993);
$imap = imap_open($resource, "user", "password", OP_READONLY, 1);
if($imap) echo "it works";
```

Comment: Here's one reason to collect users email passwords: If you want to migrate employee mailboxes from a cheap hoster (where they set their own passwords) to you own dedicated mailserver (e.g. using imapsync) you can save yourself a lot of trouble collecting this data. The passwords on the new server are of course auto-generated and users are forced to reset them on first login.

Comment: For the record, @mniess (re the deleted comments that were here from others); big-time kudos to you for actually reading the Tour and carefully considering how best to contribute! Moderators would have a *lot* less to do if others took a moment to do so, also.